# NullPointerException when calling setBackground on LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I created a Drawable resource file for a `LinearLayout` background. And I set Drawable in `MainActivity` using,

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.theme_default_bg);
layoutBackground.setBackground(d);
```

`layoutBackground` is the `LinearLayout`. But, when I run this it returns a `NullPointerException`. How can I solve this?

**Edit**
 I set xml background in main.xml file, and it worked. I got this error when i trying to set background from MainActivity.java

Comment: Probably layoutBackground is null

Comment: your layoutBackground is not initialized properly i think.

Comment: Let us see how you sets your layoutBackground in code and how you set it in XML of layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. The layout i'm trying to setBackground is in another layout file(activity_main.xml). So i use a `LayoutInflater`,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

layoutBackground = (LinearLayout)mainView.findViewById(R.id.layout_bg);
```

Now error solved. I'm sorry guys i wasted your time. I'm really sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try this... In your case you have not initialised the layoutBackground..

```
 RelativeLayout layoutBackground =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.background);

Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.theme_default_bg);

layoutBackground.setBackgroundResource(d);
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry i didn't poat it here but i initialised layout.

Comment: try to run it on debug and find the problem

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.theme_default_bg);
```

instead of trying to convert resource in to drawable.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but i still NullPointException.

Comment: have you initialised the layout? as in layout = (LinearLayout) findviewbyid(.....);

Comment: Yes @MixhaelStoddart